# Prove that $I$ is a maximal ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I have a question. To show that the ideal $I=\langle f(x)\rangle $ is a maximal ideal of $K[x]$ do I have to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$? Or is there an other way to prove that $I$ is a maximal ideal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $K$ is a field $K[x]$ is a PID, and there the prime elements and irreducible elements coincide, and they are the generators of maximal ideals.

Comment: rschwieb If we have to show that $I=<x^2+1>$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$,  do we have to do it like that?
$$$$
$x^2+1$ is a second degree polynomial.
$$$$
We know that $f(x)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$
$\Leftrightarrow$  $f(x)$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$.
$$$$
The roots of $x^2+1=0$ are $\pm i \notin \mathbb{R}$.
$$$$
Therefore, $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$.

So, do we conclude from that, that $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R[X]$?

Comment: @evinda Yes, that's a perfectly fine argument.

Comment: Does it suffice to do it like that or do we have to prove that $R[x]/I$ is a field?

Comment: @evinda If it did not suffice, I couldn't say it is a fine argument. You might just want to emphasize at the end that the ideal generated by $f$ is a nonzero prime ideal, hence maximal (this works in PIDs.)

Comment: I asked, because Matt Pressland said that I should show that $K[x]/I$ is a field..

Comment: @evinda He just said that you would have to prove $f$ is irreducible first, which you did. In general, it might be hard to prove it is irreducible. But they way you proved $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb R$ is correct.

Comment: rschwieb A ok...  To emphasize at the end that the ideal generated by $f$ is a nonzero prime ideal, hence maximal, do we have to show that $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$ is  an integral domain?

Comment: @evinda No, not if you know that irreducibles and prime elements are the same thing in PIDs (or more generally UFDs)

Comment: Could you explain me how I could formulate that irreducibles and prime elements are the same thing in PIDs?

Comment: Also, when we have for example $I=<X-1, Y+X^2-1>$ and we want to show that $I$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, do we have to show that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/I$ is a field?

Comment: @evinda : in that case you should work to show it is isomorphic to $\Bbb C[y]/(y)$ which is in turn isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

Comment: rschwieb How could we show that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/\langle X-1, Y+X^2-1 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[Y]/\langle Y \rangle $ ?

Comment: @evinda The intuition is that $X\equiv 1$ in that ring. Using that, what does $Y+X^2-1\equiv 0$ turn into? Formalize this by finding the isomorphism.

Comment: rschwieb How did you conclude that $X \equiv 1$ ? :/ 

Using $X \equiv 1$ we have that $Y \equiv 0$. 

What does this mean?

Comment: @evinda It looks like you're not very comfortable with quotient rings. Do a search for questions here about understanding what quotient rings look like. If you have trouble finding them, let me know. Basically, anything in the ideal you are modding out is "like zero." Because $X-1$ is in the ideal you're modding out, $X-1\equiv 0$ by definition.

Comment: rschwieb Do we have to prove that, since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID?

Comment: Also, do we use the fact that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID? If so, where do we use it?

Comment: @evinda For the first question, that depends on your teacher. My guess is that it should already be a part of what you've been taught, and you should be able to assume it without reproving it. For the second part, my original argument used the fact that PIDs are UFDs so that primes and irreducibles are the same.

Comment: rschwieb I understand :-) Could I also ask you something else?
$$$$
To show that $ker(\phi)=\langle x-1,y \rangle$ , could we do it like that?
$$$$

We consider a polynomial $p(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
$$$$
We apply the euclidean division for $p(x,y)$ and $x-1$ and we get:

$$p(x,y)=(x-1)g(x,y)+r(x,y)$$

$$deg r<1 \Rightarrow deg r=0 \Rightarrow r(x,y)=r(y)$$

$$p(x,y)=(x-1)g(x,y)+r(y)$$

We apply the euclidean division for $r(y)$ and $y$, and we get:

$$r(y)=yt(y)+b(y)$$

$$deg(b(y)) < deg(y) \Rightarrow deg(b(y))=0$$

$$r(y)=yt(y)+b$$

Comment: $$p(x,y)=(x-1)g(x,y)+yt(y)+b$$

If $p \in ker(\phi)$, we have that $\phi(p(x,y))=0 \Rightarrow b=0$.

$$p(x,y)=(x-1)g(x,y)+yt(y)$$

So, if $p(x,y) \in ker(\phi) \Rightarrow p(x,y) \in <x-1,y> \Rightarrow ker(\phi) \subseteq <x-1,y>$


Is it right so far? How can we show the equality $ker(\phi)=<x-1,y>$, so how can we show that $<x-1,y> \subseteq ker(\phi)$?

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly broad question - there could be lots of ways of proving something depending on the situation. As rschwieb points out, proving that $I$ is maximal is equivalent to proving $f$ is irreducible, but that doesn't mean you have to prove $f$ is irreducible first. You could prove that $K[x]/I$ is a field, which would imply $I$ is maximal (and therefore that $f$ is irreducible).

Comment: Matt Pressland If we have to show that $I=<x^2+1>$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$,  do we have to do it like that?
$$$$
$x^2+1$ is a second degree polynomial.
$$$$
We know that $f(x)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$
$\Leftrightarrow$  $f(x)$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$.
$$$$
The roots of $x^2+1=0$ are $\pm i \notin \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$.
$$$$
Having shown this, don't we conclude to the fact that $I$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$
? 
$$$$
Do we have to show that $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$ is a field? How could we do this?

Comment: Based on this, and the other comments, you seem to have misunderstood my point - which was that it is enough to prove that $f$ is irreducible *or* to prove that $K[x]/I$ is a field (and each will imply the other). You proved that $f$ is irreducible, so you're done. You could *instead* have proved that $K[x]/I$ is a field, but you don't have to do both. There are almost certainly other reasonable approaches as well.

Comment: Matt Pressland If I want to prove that $I$ is a maximal ideal, by showing that $f$ is irreducible, do I have to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is a field and $\mathbb{R}[x]$ a principal ideal domain?

Comment: It depends what theorems you know. There is a theorem that if $K$ is a field, then an ideal $I$ of $K[x]$ is maximal if and only if $I=\langle f\rangle$ for some irreducible $f$. The proof uses that $K[x]$ is a PID for any field $K$. If you can use this theorem, then it is enough to show $\mathbb{R}$ is a field (but you almost certainly already know this). If you can't, then you might want to prove it, at least in this case, which would require proving that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: If this question is from a course or a book, then there will be theorems that you are expected to be able to just use without reproving. That $\mathbb{R}$ is a field is definitely one of them, but I don't know what others there might be without more context.